# How to log into the database under the user?

Tags: psql, postgresql-9.5

I install postres9 on linux mint 18. I login under default postres user. I try create new user and login under this user.

```
kalinin@lenovo ~ $ sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@lenovo ~ $ psql
psql (9.5.16)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE db_test;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# CREATE USER user_test WITH PASSWORD 'qwerty';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# 
postgres=# 
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "db_test" to user_test;
GRANT
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 user_test |                                                            | {}

postgres=# \l
                                   List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges    
-------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------------------
 db_test     | postgres | UTF8     | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres          +
             |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres +
             |          |          |             |             | user_test=CTc/postgres
 postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 | 

postgres=# \q
postgres@lenovo ~ $ exit
logout
kalinin@lenovo ~ $ sudo -i -u user_test
sudo: unknown user: user_test
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

you see what i am creating new user with password and new database. after that i exit from postgres and try login again. But login failed. Please help fix it.

Comment: No need for `sudo`, just pass the correct username to psql: `psql -U user_test`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name`
kalinin@lenovo ~/python/joba_finder $ sudo psql -U user_test 
[sudo] password for kalinin: 
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "user_test"
kalinin@lenovo ~/python/joba_finder $ 
`

Comment: You do **not** need `sudo`

Comment: Correct, sudo is not necessary. And the database user you created "user_test" is not a system user, so sudo to that user will never work. But you might need to setup pg_hba.conf, when using psql -U.